# Excel Combobox _Click activating on Pivot table refresh

Tags: vba, excel, combobox, excel-2013

I have a `comboBox` on the same sheet as a few pivot tables. The `comboBox` updates the pivot table filters depending on what's selected.

The problem is, when the pivot table refreshes (to set the new filters) it will active the combo box `_click`function, starting a loop.

Is there a way around this? Why is the pivot table refresh activating the combo box?

This is the code inside the _Click event:

```
Private Sub cmb_SkuSelect_Click()
    Dim xlSheetSort As Worksheet
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim xlCell As Range
    Dim skuValue As Integer

    Set xlSheetSort = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("Sort")

    lastRow = xlSheetSort.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

    With xlSheetSort.Range("B1:B" & lastRow)
        Set xlCell = .Find(cmb_SkuSelect.Value, LookIn:=xlValues)
        If Not xlCell Is Nothing Then
            skuValue = xlSheetSort.Range("A" & xlCell.Row).Value
        End If
    End With

    updatePivot skuValue
End Sub
```

updatePivot:

```
Public Sub updatePivot(ByVal sku As Integer)
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pt2 As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim Field2 As PivotField
    Dim newSku As String

    Set pt = Worksheets("Sku Inventory").PivotTables("SkuInfo")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Sku Number")

    Set pt2 = Worksheets("Sku Inventory").PivotTables("InventoryInfo")
    Set Field2 = pt2.PivotFields("Sku Number")

    newSku = sku

    With pt
        Field.CurrentPage = newSku
        pt.RefreshTable
    End With

    With pt2
        Field2.CurrentPage = newSku
        pt2.RefreshTable
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What's `updatePivot` doing?

Comment: it is updating the 2 pivot tables on the sheet with the SKU passed to it. I will update the original with the code.

Answer (score 0):

thry like this

```
Public Sub updatePivot(ByVal sku As Integer)
    Dim pt As PivotTable
    Dim pt2 As PivotTable
    Dim Field As PivotField
    Dim Field2 As PivotField
    Dim newSku As String

    Set pt = Worksheets("Sku Inventory").PivotTables("SkuInfo")
    Set Field = pt.PivotFields("Sku Number")

    Set pt2 = Worksheets("Sku Inventory").PivotTables("InventoryInfo")
    Set Field2 = pt2.PivotFields("Sku Number")

    newSku = sku

    With pt
        With Field
            .Orientation = xlHidden
            pt.RefreshTable
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .CurrentPage = newSku
        End With
    End With

    With pt2
        With Field2
            .Orientation = xlHidden
            pt2.RefreshTable
            .Orientation = xlPageField
            .CurrentPage = newSku
        End With

    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Unfortunately this doesn't work. It still fires the _Click event of the combo box when anything updates on the page. With your solution I am getting the error "unable to set the orientation".
The only solution I have found so far, is to set the value of the combo box to "" right before it calls the update method.